# Can`t even create the table

Tags: php, google-fusion-tables, google-api-php-client

I can`t find good samples of using php google api with fusiontables, so this code absolutely doesn`t work. How I could understant there is two ways to work with api - sending post queries by curl and use functions, as in example: $service->table->listTable(). Somebody, please tell me, is there some list of this functions and parameters for them? I`ve tried find listTable() here https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/ . I couldn`t understand how to use 'properties' described in reference. Maybe exists easy way to create named table with descriptions and one column in one command?

```
 <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', 'On');
ini_set('error_log', 'error.log');
set_time_limit(0);
require_once '/vendor/autoload.php';
$clientId = 'sdsdsadfffdsfsadffsdasdf';
$clientSecret = 'difdsafasdasdsa_';
$redirectUrl = 'http://localhost/fusiontable/dorgen.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($clientId);
$client->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirectUrl);
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables'));

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $client->getAccessToken();
    exit;
}
print '<a href="' . $client->createAuthUrl() . '">Authenticate</a>';
$service = new Google_Service_fusiontables($client);
$myCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($myCurl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/tables',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array('
 "columns": [
  {
   "name": "Test"
  }
 ],
 "isExportable": true,
 "name": "Trst",
 "description": "Test"

')))
);
$response = curl_exec($myCurl);
curl_close($myCurl);

echo "Answer: ".$response;
print_r($service->table->listTable());
```